# Why are low m,n modes more dominant?

Tags: plasma-physics

Consider an axially symmetric, toroidal, magnetized plasma with some safety factor (q) profile. A flux surface has q=m/n where m is the number of toroidal transits and n is the number of poloidal transits for a magnetic field line.

Why do the dominant modes have low m and n? For example, q=99/100 and q=1/1 have almost the same curvature, but q=1/1 is the more important mode when considering instabilities.

Comment: This sounds like a Tokamak question, am I correct?  If so, then I have a few guesses, but they would be significantly improved if a few things were explained more clearly in your question.  My initial guess is that higher m,n modes attenuate over shorter spatial scales.  In a Tokamak plasma, that would be cm's to mm's (or perhaps even less… I forgot what the typical Debye/inertial lengths are in most Tokamaks).  So my guess is that lower m,n modes are more important for confinement and higher m,n modes play a role in heating (there may also be growth rate differences).

Comment: Yes tokamak / magnetized plasma confinement question.